# Найти все корни уравнения xy=z

Tags: java

Не могу придумать хотя бы алгоритм нахождения всех корней уравнений xy = z.
Потом нужно будет его запрограммировать

x,y,z - натуральные числа.
z- вводится с клавиатуры.
Например z = 2. Тогда x = 1,2; y = 2,1;

Comment: Корней - бесконечное количество. Ничего не хотите уточнить?

Comment: @MBo ой, уточнил

Comment: Сперва разложить Z на простые множители. Затем посчитать количество подмножеств.

Answer (score 0):

Для решения этой задачи достаточно проверить все делители Z, начиная с 1 и до квадратного корня из Z. Если очередное число k является делителем (что проверяется с помощью операции целочисленного модуля `%`), то выводим две (если k не корень из Z) пары `(k, z/k)` и `(z/k, k)`

Comment: При больших Z шанс дождаться завершения процесса перебора становится весьма невелик.

Comment: @Akina Ну надо же с чего-то начать.